# Facebook C# getting all the feed of a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to get all the post with this HTTPRequest

> var response =
>                       wb.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/pageName/feed?access_token=123|123&limit=200");

I guess it has something to do with maximum limit of return because I can only receive only 24 post but the page has if not hundred but thousands post. It has a lot of comments so I'm thinking of disabling it on the request but I do not think that is possible.

Or

I can get the next post after getting the first page

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get all posts in one requests, check for a paging object in the result:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

For example, you can use a recursive function to get all posts, but keep in mind that you may hit the API limits if there are thousands of posts to go through.

Comment: just make sure you know what a "recursive function" is, and check for the "paging" object in the response. there is a "next" value in it, that´s the api call for the next loop of the function call - for the next batch of posts.